# Ambiguous Reference in source

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]

I don't know what is the problem in my project i just exclude and then include again.

what are the reasons from having this problem. thank you

Comment: have you tried deleting all the binaries, rebuild all from VS IDE?

Comment: not yet. how do i delete binaries and what will be the effect to other?

Comment: if you have all the source code, don't have external dependencies - just delete the binaries of each project in solution (esp. the one that you are referring). Build location is configurable per project - so you can delete just the projects the current project referencing also. Then do a 'rebuild all' from build menu.

Comment: Do you have two classes called "frmManagerUsers" in that namespace? That is by far the easiest way to get an error like that.